# Why lxsession-logout slows down X window system?

Tags: ati, graphics, xorg, lxde, lxsession

In Lubuntu, if you click on the shutdown button, the one to the right on the panel; the whole window system slows down and any click you make takes more than 20 seconds to complete.

From around the web it seems like this is a problem with the drivers for AMD cards, however I can't state it as a fact.

I'm using a SAPPHIRE HD 7770.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem has not been found, but there is a solution:

Update your video card drivers.

In my case: [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx)?](https://askubuntu.com/a/126513/6506)

Before doing any changes execute this:

```
fgl_glxgears
```

And again after you are done. This will give you some data for comparisons afterwards.

Comment: You should modify your question because your answer applies to **amd**.

Comment: Done. Since I do not know the real cause for the problem, I can't tell if it is an AMD exclusive problem.